# System Calls fundamentals and what will be out put on this program

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

I want to know the output from this program it about system call. I try to understand but it's hard.

```
int main (void) {
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork(); 
  if (pid > 0) {
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
      printf(" I AM VU : %d\n", i);
      sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
  } 
  else if (pid == 0) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      printf(" I have no child: %d\n", j);
      sleep(1);
    }
    exit(0);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use proper formatting and try to post valid code.

Comment: You'll get a good estimate of the output by simply compiling and running it.

Comment: First of all, what language is it?  (We can guess easily enough on this one, but being explicit is a good thing.)  Second, what does this have to do with "artificial-intelligence"?  Third, if you want to know the output then you can always run it.  Stepping through the code as it runs, what part doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: Please: the signature of main is int main ( int argc, char **argv ); not int main ( void );. A small point perhaps but, to eliminate any question,let's do it right.

Comment: @Pete: `int main(void)` is one of two valid forms for the main program in C.  See §5.1.2.2.1 ¶1 of C99: "The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
parameters:
`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner."

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to show the headers you included - it should be `<errno.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>` and `<unistd.h>`, AFAICS.

Answer (score 2):

After you get this code to compile and run, the parent will output something like:

```
 I AM VU : 0
 I AM VU : 1
 I AM VU : 2
 I AM VU : 3
 I AM VU : 4
```

The single child will output something like:

```
 I have no child: 0
 I have no child: 1
 I have no child: 2
 I have no child: 3
 I have no child: 4
```

The five lines from the child will almost certainly be mixed up with the parent's output lines, so you'll see something like this on the screen:

```
I AM VU : 0
I have no child: 0
I AM VU : 1
I have no child: 1
I have no child: 2
I have no child: 3
I AM VU : 2
I have no child: 4
I AM VU : 3
I AM VU : 4
```

If the fork() fails, the program will output something like:

`can't fork xx`  where xx is errno.

**NOTE** I don't think of `fork( )` as a *system* call but as a call to a *library* function. Small difference in practice and effect, but still.

Comment: And those output lines may be arbitrarily interleaved.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- Oh, yes. I'll edit the ans to show that. Thanks, I forgot all about it.

Answer (score 0):

'man fork' will answer questions on what fork returns.

Compile the code and use 'strace -f a.out' to follow what it's doing.

I'm not sure what that program is looping and sleeping for. My guess is it's just to demonstrate that the order of the output from the two processes can't be predicted.